# Attaching Microcontroller to DAC evaluation board

Tags: pins, digital-analog-conversion

For an independent undergraduate research project I'm trying to construct a digital feedback loop. I have never used an Arduino, or done much electrical/computer engineering, so I'm just taking things one thing at a time. 
I've been given this
[microcontroller](https://store.digilentinc.com/uc32-arduino-programmable-pic32-microcontroller-board/)
and this [DAC eval board](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/eval-ad5780.html), and now I'm just trying to put them together.

From reading, I need to  attach jumper cables from #16 here to 
[image: micro-controller schematic]
the pins on the Eval Board here, 
[image: Digital Input Pin Description]

but I don't know where to find information on them, so I don't know which to plug into what. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAC uses the SPI protocol.  For that you want to connect it to the SPI header. That's the 6-pin (3x2) header numbered 11 on the uC32.

Connect:

- The uC32's SCK pin to the DAC's SCLK
- The uC32's SDO pin (MOSI) to the DAC's SDIN pin.
- The uC32's SDI pin (MISO) to the DAC's SDO pin.

The other pins (I am not sure what they all do off hand, but the datasheet details them) can connect to any GPIO pins you like (except pins 11-13 which duplicate the SPI header - so you could use those instead if you prefer - 11=MOSI, 12=MISO, 13=SCK).

Comment: Where would I read about if I need to ground the DAC to the microcontroller? I've edited the post to have the right DAC evaluation board, but the guide for the EVALAD5780 also does not explain their acronyms for the pins.

Comment: The pins are all defined in the [AD5780 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad5780.pdf).  Of course you have to connect the grounds together, otherwise you don't have a circuit.

Comment: OK, I think a better question would be where should I read to learn about setting up a serial circuit like this? For example, the DAC has two DGND pins so I don't know where to ground. Also, the J8 pins which are the SPI do not seem to be labeled so idk which is which, can I just use 11-13 since they're duplicates?

Comment: Yes, you can use 11-13. The SPI pins are detailed in the uC32 user guide. Connect _all_ ground pins together.

Comment: just checking back in, don't I need a Slave Select, SS or SYNC pin somewhere? I can connect the SYNC to the micro-controller and  just set that Low via any pin right?

Comment: Yep, any pin at all.

Comment: Complete shot in the dark here, but if you're able to look here, I have more questions. I don't know how to debug my SPI connections. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/428571/operating-ad5780-eval-board-via-microcontroller